# DOM not updating with bound $scope object

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an AngularJS app that I'm trying to utilize an overlay on. Basically, I have a couple of panels, and when the user clicks one, it should set `$scope.selectedPanel` to the clicked panel, and then show the overlay. Instead, it shows the overlay without updating it via the data-bound `$scope.selectedPanel`. It DOES update the object, but this change is not reflected in what is displayed to the user.

**Calling HTML**

```
<div ng-click="pickPanel(panel);" ng-repeat="panel in panels track by $index">
    <p>{{panel.title}}</p>  
</div>
```

**Javascript to set selectedPanel & initial Variables**

```
$scope.panels = [];

$scope.selectedPanel = "";

$scope.panels.push(
    {panelID:1, 
     title:"Panel #1", 
     room:"",
     startTime: "Friday 2:30 PM",
     endTime: "Friday 3:30 PM",
     hostedBy: "The Host",
     description:"This is a description of the panel"}
);

$scope.panels.push(
    {panelID:2, 
     title:"Panel #2", 
     room:"",
     startTime: "Friday 3:30 PM",
     endTime: "Friday 3:30 PM",
     hostedBy: "The Host",
     description:"This is a description of the panel"}
);

$scope.pickEvent = function(panel){
    setTimeout(function() {     
        $scope.selectedPanel = panel;
        document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'block';
     }, 1000);
}
```

**Overlay HTML**

```
<div id="overlay">
    <div id="overlayContainer">
        <div class="card">                          
            <p>{{selectedPanel.title}}</p>              
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So what seems to be happening is that the first time I click one of the panels, it goes off to the `pickEvent` method, sets the selected event, and then displays the overlay - however, the overlay is essentially 1 step behind. So when I click the FIRST panel for the first time, the overlay will display a `null` title. However, if I close it, and click a second panel, then the title of the FIRST panel I picked will be displayed. Then if I pick a third panel, the panel I picked second will be displayed.

Is there something I'm missing with AngularJS, especially where I set my `$scope.selectedPanel` to the passed panel, that forces a refresh on the overlay HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are modifying the model without angular knowing about it. Change `onclick` with `ng-click` and `setTimeout` with `$resource` to let angular handle its bindings.

If you update the model from an external source (`onclick`, `intervals`, etc) you have to let angular now that something changed by calling [`$scope.$apply()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply), or use [`ng-click`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) and [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) instead.

Comment: I'm already using `ng-click` for the part that is failing - the onclick is just a function that turns OFF the Overlay - removing the onClick for it completely also did not help. I edited my original question to reflect this.

Also, where do I call `$scope.apply()`? I tried it in the pickEvent method after I set the `overlay` display to `block`, and it still doesn't update.

Comment: Calling it after `$scope.selectedPanel = panel;` should be enough, are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: ah, it was `$scope.$apply()` -- didn't get a console error for some reason though, which worries me. But yep, doing the `$apply()` ended up working for me. Thanks so much!

Comment: I also found another issue, you are calling pickPanel and your function its called pickEvent :S, didn't notice that the first time. And sorry about the $apply typo :p

Comment: You're good! And yeah, I was stripping out about 50 other lines of code that weren't relevant to the situation, and must have re-named the pickPanel to pickEvent or vice versa. Either way, thanks for the help, and good eye!